# HCatalog/Hive table creation does not import data into /app/hive/warehouse folder in hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue, hortonworks-data-platform, hcatalog

I ran into a very weird problem within a hadoop cluster (HDP 2.2) I setup in Amazon EC2 (3 data nodes + one name node + one secondary name node). Hue server runs on the main name node and hive server runs on the secondary name node. I was using Hue web interface to create table "mytable" in HCatalog using a CSV file loaded into HDFS. The table creation returned successfully without error. The table was created and displayed in the Hue web interface.  However, when I tried to query the table, it returned 0 record. I went to the /app/hive/warehouse folder, I could see the table folder "mytable" was created, but the CSV file was never copied into that folder. I reproduced the same behavior using hive shell.

If I does the same operation in the HDP sandbox VM, everything works as expected. After the table creation, the /app/hive/warehouse/mytable folder contains the CSV file I imported into the table.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. I realized the server in the cluster with the hive server running is low on physical memory. After free up some memory on the box, the hcatalog table creation operation worked as expected.